# selection issue after matching

Tags: algorithm, select, match

I want to know if there are some keywords to study the following issue:

---

Searching K characters in a dictionary (like LZ77) and find out all their matching length and index at the same time.
For instance,

```
           char A B C D E F G H I J
   match length 4 2 1 3 3 5 2 1 2 1
          index 2 5 7 0 9 1 3 4 8 6
```

If I want to know how many codes will be output, there are some ways to group them. The most intuitive way is select the index from char[0] and group them by the matching length.
So it will be

```
           char A B C D E F G H I J
   match length 4 - - - 3 - - 1 2 -
          index 2 - - - 9 - - 4 8 -
```

The code made by {index, len} will be {2,4},{9,3},{4,1},{8,2}.
The code number is four.

Or the characters can be grouped by the length no bigger than the matching length, say,

```
           char A B C D E F G H I J
   match length 4 - - - 1 5 - - - -
          index 2 - - - 9 1 - - - -
```

The code made by {index, len} will be {2,4},{9,1},{1,5}, which can output less code number than the previous way.

---

I know there are still many methods to select the output codes, and there are some benefit for the choosing methods. (complexity, speed, minimal output code...)

My question is, are there some algorithms discussing this kind of selection issue? Or some keywords I can look for? It's really confusing if I can't get the searching keyword, then I won't be able to begin the study.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [Deflate RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) discusses "lazy matching", which is an attempt to heuristically select better matches by looking into the future (or undoing things in the past) a bit (fortunately the future is available). The idea there is that if you could select a match at the current index but not doing so enables you to select a longer match, then just output the current symbol as a literal and take the longer match next. That's not anywhere close to optimal, it's just an improvement compared to greedily taking all matches no matter what.

Storer and Szymanski gave an algorithm for the "optimal parse" (under some assumptions, notably that you know the bit-cost of your choices, which you usually don't), by working backwards over the file and recording for every position the optimal choice and how many bits it would take.